# SharePoint C# move attachment and keep creation values in SP 2019

Tags: 2010, development, attachments, ssom, spfile

We want to copy item attachments from one Item in one site collection to another item in a different site collection using C# (Server Side Object Model).

Is it possible to keep or replicate the Original Creation Variables: Author and TimeCreated fields ?

SPFile.TimeCreated
SPFile.Author

Thank you